# How to estimate the sum of N observations taking from a normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I would like to get 95% confidence interval for the sum of N observation taken from a normal distribution.

I know how to build a confidence interval for a single observation but not for the sum of many.

Additionally if I have a sum taken from a normal distribution N1 and a sum taken frmo another normal distribution N2 with different mean and sd, how can I get a 95% C.I. for the sum of the 2 sums?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your question sounds like you are looking for a [prediction-interval](/questions/tagged/prediction-interval), not a [confidence-interval](/questions/tagged/confidence-interval). [There is a difference.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info) In your case, you seem to be looking for a quantile.
2. Assuming that your draws are independent, [the sum of normal variables is again normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables). Just add the means and the variances.

   Thus, if $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then an $\alpha$ quantile for the sum is $q_\alpha(n\mu, n\sigma^2)$.

   And if $X_1, \dots, X_n \sim N(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ and $Y_1, \dots, Y_m \sim N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$, then an $\alpha$ quantile for the sum is $q_\alpha(n\mu_1+m\mu_2, n\sigma_1^2+m\sigma_2^2)$.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, I was never tought in the university about prediction intervals, that is exactly what I am looking for.